# How to resize Twitter Bootstrap modal dynamically based on data content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm loading modal with remote content in this way

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="my-page.php">Click to open Modal</a>
```

and now I need to set also size of modal based on content...
Then I add data-class

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-class="modal-lg" href="my-page.php">Click to open Modal</a>

<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-class="modal-sm" href="my-page2.php">Click to open Modal</a>
```

And then I have tried this to set the size

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  var class = $(this).data('class');
  $(this).find('.modal-dialog').addClass(class);
});
```

but not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code don't catch the element that open the modal:

> var class = $(this).data('class');

in this context `this` refer to modal.

Furthermore, `class` is a reserved words in ECMAScript5/6 (you cannot use it as variable name).

To grab the correct `data-class` value, you can use `relatedTarget` property of the `event` (passed as function argument).

Finally, remove any css classes that may be present and add the correct class:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

  var _trigger = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var _class = _trigger.data('class');

  $(this)
    .find('.modal-dialog')
    .removeClass('modal-lg modal-sm')
    .addClass( _class);

});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzQByR

PS I use `show.bs.modal` event, because it is fired immediately when the show instance method is called ([see the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events)) and, in the demo, I use `<button>` instead of `<a>`